Persistent Loading Indicator Issue in Outlook WebAdd-in After Full Initialization
I have developed an Outlook web add-in using TypeScript, managed by Webpack. While the add-in functionality works as expected, I am facing an issue with a loading indicator that never disappears, even after the add-in has fully initialized.
I have tried the following steps to resolve this issue:
Ensured Initialization: Used Office.Initialize along with Office.Ready to confirm that the add-in is fully initialized.
Parent Communication: Passed the initialize event to the parent to ensure it recognizes that the add-in has been loaded and initialized.
Configuration Checks: Tested various configurations, including different polyfills and tsconfig settings, to identify any potential causes.
Despite these efforts, the loading indicator persists, even when the add-in fails to load entirely.The "Loading..." progress bar remains active indefinitely, suggesting that there might be an issue with how the initialization state is being communicated or processed.
Has anyone experienced a similar problem, or could you provide guidance on how to resolve this persistent loading indicator issue in Outlook Web Add-ins? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.enter image description here
The following how the addin is initiallized:
Office.onReady((info) => {
  const item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
  if (item) {
    $("#subject").text(item.subject);
    $("#from").text(item.from.emailAddress);
  }
  if (info.host === Office.HostType.Outlook) {
    start();
  }
});

Following are the polyfils that i am importing
enter image description here
Following is Our tsConfig:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom",
      "es2015.promise"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "lib",
    "lib-amd"
  ],
  "ts-node": { 
    "files": true 
  }
}


in your taskpane.html give background color white to body

Thanks alot , This solved the problem
